# Flutter ExpansionPanelList - expansionCallback not working

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-provider

I am implementing the `ExpansionPanelList` by using the `Provider` package instead of making the `Widget` be `statefulWidget`. However, the `expansionCallback` never gets working. If I click on the first collapsed list on the screen, it will never get expanded. Specifically, `data[0].isExpanded` is always `false` in `SummitView.dart`. There's no error reported in the console.

Here's my `SummitView.dart`:

```
import 'package:delta_y/modules/summits/model/Item.dart';
import 'package:delta_y/modules/summits/model/ItemsList.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SummitView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Summit/Milestone"),
        ),
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ItemsList(),
          child: Summit(),
        ));
  }
}

class Summit extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final itemModel = Provider.of<ItemsList>(context);
    // List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);
    itemModel.generateItems(8);

    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              itemModel.setExpanded(index, isExpanded);
              print("INDEX : $index ... $isExpanded");
            },
            children: itemModel.data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
              bool isData0Expanded = itemModel.data[0].isExpanded;
              print('**********');
              print(isData0Expanded);
              print('**********');

              return ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.headerValue),
                  );
                },
                body: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                    subtitle:
                    Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onTap: () {
                      itemModel.deleteItem(item);
                    }),
                isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.white,
                onPrimary: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Create Summit'),
            ),
            widthFactor: 0.9,
          )),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Here's the `ItemsList.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'Item.dart';

class ItemsList extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Item> _data;

  List<Item> get data => _data;

  generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
    _data = List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
      return Item(
        headerValue: 'Panel $index',
        expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
      );
    });
  }

  setExpanded(int index, bool isExpanded) {
    _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  deleteItem(Item item) {
    _data.removeWhere((currentItem) => item == currentItem);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here's the `Item.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item{
  Item({
    @required this.expandedValue,
    @required this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line:

```dart
class Summit extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // ... other lines

    itemModel.generateItems(8); <----
```

When calling a method within the build(), it will get called everytime the screen receive an event from the `Provider`. In this case, your list of items keep being generated everytime, which make the `isExpanded` always `false`.

To fix this, it's best to add some conditions to prevent the list of items from resetting, or generate the items when creating the `ItemsList`, something like:

```dart
body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => ItemsList()..generateItems(8),
    child: Summit(),
```

Result:

[image]